# Generate a specefic url for the api

Tags: api, spring-boot, security

I want to make the client able to use a service from my API, but I can't share my server URL. Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have tiny api/service deployed to another server which underhood calls your real api. And in this case client will call your proxy url and will not know what is actual endpoint under it. This is how usually developers create backend for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDN service, CDN will hide your server IP also protect your hosting infrastructure. you can start with cloudFlare CDN.